# Dropping external table clears global temp table populated from external table

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I am using external tables to load data from files. This data has a lot of processing it needs to go through, and the external tables are dynamically created, so the data is supposed to be loaded into the external table, then into a global temp table, then the external table is deleted and the processing continues on the data within the temp table. The structure of the temp table matches that of the external table.

Dropping the external table is clearing the global temp table.

This all happens in the same proc, so I don't think it's a session issue.

The proc looks like this:

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE Upload_Data_File
(
  filename IN varchar2
)
IS
  can_create_table char(1) := 'Y';
  ext_table_name varchar2(200) := filename;
  sql_to_run varchar(5000) := '';
BEGIN
/*****************************************************************************
  Create external table/load file data
*****************************************************************************/
  BEGIN
    ext_table_name := replace(ext_table_name, '.', '_');
    ext_table_name := 'ext_' || ext_table_name;
    sql_to_run := 'CREATE TABLE ' || ext_table_name || '
                       (    
                          ROW1 CHAR(1 BYTE), 
                          ROW2 CHAR(1 BYTE), 
                          RECORD_TEXT VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
                          RECORD_NUMBER NUMBER
                       ) 
                       ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
                       ( 
                          TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
                          DEFAULT DIRECTORY FILE_DIRECTORY
                          ACCESS PARAMETERS
                          ( 
                            RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE 
                            FIELDS 
                            (
                              ROW1 char(1)
                              ,ROW2 char(1)
                              ,record_text position(3:203)
                              ,record_number recnum
                            )
                          )
                          LOCATION
                         ( 
                            ''' || filename || '''
                          )
                       )
                       REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_to_run;

    can_create_table := 'Y';
  END;

  IF can_create_table = 'Y' THEN
    /***************************************************************************
      To avoid the use of a lot of dynamic SQL, a single statement will move 
        the rows from the external table to a global temp table.
    ***************************************************************************/
    sql_to_run := 'INSERT INTO Global_File_Upload (
                        ROW1,
                        ROW2,
                        record_text,
                        record_number
                       )
                       SELECT
                        ROW1,
                        ROW2,
                        record_text,
                        record_number
                       FROM ' || ext_table_name;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_to_run;

    /***************************************************************************
      The external table is no longer needed and can be dropped
    ***************************************************************************/
    sql_to_run := 'DROP TABLE ' || ext_table_name;
    --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_to_run;

    /***************************************************************************
      Process the records in the temp table
    ***************************************************************************/
  END IF;
END IF;
```

As long as the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE for dropping the external table is commented out, the procedure runs correctly. But if I allow that statement to run, the temp table has no data in it to be processed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My wager would be that the global temporary table was defined as `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS` rather than `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS`.  Since DDL like creating or dropping a table implicitly commits, a global temporary table that deletes rows when a transaction ends would clear out its data when any DDL was executed in the session.  If you want the data to be preserved, you'd need to define the table as `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS`.

Taking a step back, though, the architecture seems problematic.  Creating and dropping objects dynamically is almost never the appropriate solution.  From the example you posted, it appears that you are dropping and creating the external table just to change the file that you're loading from.  It would be preferable to just keep the table and change the file name

```
ALTER TABLE external_table_name
  LOCATION( '<<new file name>>' );
```

It also seems unlikely that you would want to load the data into a temporary table rather than just querying the external table directly.  The temporary table isn't buying you anything unless you're doing something like building indexes on the temp table in order to make processing more efficient.  Most loads from external files, though, are just doing a single pass through the data in order to load into a permanent table.

Comment: ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS does the trick. The architecture was designed this way because users are uploading files from a website. If I was just altering the external table's location, a second user would have to wait for the external table to be free before being able to upload the file.